# How to use human sound as input in Android?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am developing one application. Suppose user save question with 4 option and one answer
in database. and Retrieve it in the format of speech. Apps ask question to user with
option and user just speak option then apps speak whether result is correct or not.
My question is when apps ask question and user Speak the answer then how this match to each
other sound?
Give me Some hint or reference document or code.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dude your question is not clear... you are looking for voice regonisation application(i.e) accepts user input in voice (or) application which voice out the options (i.e) Text to speech TTS?
if you are looking for some text to speech application then you can look into this sample 
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/TtsEngine/index.html

else look at other examples given in other answers...

Answer (score 1):

Try google speech/voice recongnition. Some examples: 
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html 
and 
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy option to match speech. I guess you'll have to match loudness, frequency and length of the answer with your database.

Of course you could try Google's Voice Recognition API (per Intent: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this sample code for some code that asks a question using TextToSpeech and then uses SpeechRecognition to check if the answer was correct.

https://github.com/gmilette/Say-the-Magic-Word-

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it myself, but iSpeech has an Android SDK for both text to speech and voice recognition. Their voices sound pretty good compared to a lot of the others, so they may be worth a try. They also seem to allow for direct API access.

http://www.ispeech.org/developers